# Replace the Facebook Like Buttons on a Website with the New Built-in Like Action 

Tags: web, facebook-opengraph

On my website, I want to keep track of (probably store in db) how many times an item has been liked by facebook users.

Can I create a new **like action** (built-in type) **using opengraph** and set its **Action Link URL**  to my website URL, where I can get the user request, process & then publish the story (against the object) to user's feed. And can I use this like action feature on my website, in places where I use the like button.